# multi touch in Qt(qml) android aplication

Tags: android, qt, qml, multi-touch, qtquick2

How to make multi touch suported image viewer on android using `qt`?
I tried to run QtWidget Example on android, it works tarrible.

Comment: Why would you run the widget examples on Android? Have you tried the QtQuickControls examples, too?

Comment: @LaszloPapp Actually, Android supports most of QWidget-s just fine :)

Comment: @mlvljr: some support != should be used for fluid mobile UI with multi-touch and all that. Also, QtWidgets is not yet QtQuickWidgets, so that is not what the title writes (qml).

Comment: @LaszloPapp some support != should not be used for all that -- either; but I agree that the question is somewhat vague :)

Comment: @mlvljr: the support mostly exists for old applications not to break completely. It is not the preferred direction by the Qt Project in my understanding. In fact, I have never seen multi-touch working properly with QWidgets. I personally do not see the question vague. He is asking why QtWidgets do not work. My answer is try the real qml examples instead.

Comment: @LaszloPapp no, it *is* vague, let's have a quarrel in the best tradition of SO!